# Function that return integer or empty string

Tags: vb.net

I need to have a function that if a string is = "" return "" else return the cint of the string. I wrote the function below:

```
Function returnIntWithNull(intString As String )    
        Return If(intString="","",CInt(intString )) 
    End Function
```

But I get the below warning

> Function without an 'As' clause; return type of Object assumed

and

> Cannot infer a common type because more than one type is possible; 'Object' assumed.

In my code I need to call the function as :

`New JArray({returnIntWithNull(getRow.getDrawOffsets)})),`

i need that the Jproperty if the GetDrawOffsets return "" will be equal to "advancedraws":[] 
else if return a string that contain a number must be in the format "advancedraws":[65]

Comment: Every integer can be represented as string. Are there any technical reasons that prevent you from `.ToString()` on the input parameter, so that you can use your function as is? (it requires string). Then I'd use `Int.TryParse()`. It may be well possible that `TryCast` accepts `Object`, but I can't easily test the scenario, especially with your conditions.

Comment: The function is used in this call 
New JProperty("advancedraws",New JArray({returnIntWithNull(getRow.getDrawOffsets)})),

i need that the Jproperty if the GetDrawOffsets return "" will be equal to "advancedraws":[] else if return a string that contain a number must be in the format "advancedraws":[65]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the return type as `Object` and specify one of the results of the `If` operator to be `Object` also.

```
Function returnIntWithNull(intString As String) As Object
    Return If(intString = String.Empty, String.Empty, CObj(CInt(intString))) 
End Function
```

`If` requires that the two results be the same type or one to inherit the other.  `String` and `Integer` don't satisfy either of those options.  By casting one result as type `Object`, you satisfy the second option.